# Easy? mistake in python syntax (If-Statement)

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, syntax

I am losing my mind.

This code is giving me a syntax error complaining about the second if statement.
Shouldn't everything be working? I fail to see the mistake, I tried adding an else statement but that just makes that the syntax error..

Help highly appreciated!

```
inputpdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("testfolder\\merge.pdf")

for i in range(inputpdf.numPages):
    num = range(inputpdf.numPages)[-1]
    if (num % 2) != 0:
        print(i)
        output = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
        output.addPage(inputpfd.getPage(range(num))
    if (i % 2) == 0:
        output = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
        output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
        output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i+1))
        with open("document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
            output.write(outputStream)
```

Comment: FWIW: Python 3.10 will issue a much more useful warning in this case (`SyntaxError: '(' was never closed`), which should make it easier to catch typos like this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

you missed one enclosing brace `)`:

```
import PyPDF2

inputpdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("testfolder\\merge.pdf")

for i in range(inputpdf.numPages):
    num = range(inputpdf.numPages)[-1]
    if (num % 2) != 0:
        print(i)
        output = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
        output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(range(num)))
    if (i % 2) == 0:
        output = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
        output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
        output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i+1))
        with open("document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
            output.write(outputStream)
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
output.addPage(inputpfd.getPage(range(num)) //no enclosing brace.
```

with

```
output.addPage(inputpfd.getPage(range(num)))
```